# Yii Property "AuthWebUser.controllerMap" is not defined

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, yii-extensions

I tried to setup a new Yii application and use Yii-auth for user management.. actuayll i was already able to create the roles, but when I login as admin/admin and navigate to user/index it throws this error:

Property "AuthWebUser.controllerMap" is not defined.

Maybe somebody has a clue for that .. i checked and AuthWebUser indeed does not have this property but why is it asked for?

Comment: I think you should use Yii-Rights Extension for the RBAC management. I have also used other Extensions but I find that to be the best.

Comment: [`controllerMap`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#controllerMap-detail) is a property of the application. Make sure, you didn't mess up your `main.php` config file somehow.

Comment: you are right... i had user component and auth component at the same time